# Parameter value [1234567890] did not match expected type [scala.Option (n/a)]

Tags: scala, spring-boot, hibernate

so I want to search one value in 3 columns in the MYSQL table and write JPA query like this:
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE 123 IN(col1, col2, col3);`
so the problem is col2 and col3 are nullable they may have null value so the type of these columns is `Option[String]` in the entity class.

so I tried something like this in JpaRepository:

```
@Repository
trait ContactRepo extends JpaRepository[Contact, Long] {

  def findFirstByCol1OrCol2OrCol3(c1: String, c2: scala.Option[String], c3: scala.Option[String]): Contact
}
```

and while calling this:

```
val optionData: scala.Option[String] = scala.Option("1234567890")
val someData: scala.Some[String] = scala.Some("12345678980")
val simpleStringData: String = "1234567890"
val contact = contactRepo.findFirstByCol1OrCol2OrCol3(simpleStringData, optionData, optionData)
```

I tried all variables(optionData, someData and simpleStringData) but I keep getting this error:

```
Parameter value [1234567890] did not match expected type [scala.Option (n/a)]
```

I tried `OnIsNull` also but still not working
I don't know what I'm missing I think its some small mistake that I don't understand

**problem:** how can i write JPA query for `SELECT * FROM table WHERE 123 IN(col1, col2, col3);`
**Note:** type of col2 and col3 are `scala.Option[String]`

Comment: What is even the point of using **Scala** if you are going to be using **Java** frameworks that doesn't understand the **Scala** types and because are based on reflection will never be idiomatic. Take a look to things like **play** and **slick** if you like big OOP frameworks or to **cask** and **anorm** if you like small and pragmatic libraries or to **http4s** and **doobie** if you want to dive deep in full FP, or to **akka-http** and **quill** if you want something more mixed between FP and OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old question but I faced the same problem today and I solved it by checking the exact value that required to the function. When you create JPA query with option type then query mapped variable in entity class is also defined as option so while passing values to the query method you need to pass it like:
`Option[Option[String]]`
so in your method it should be:

```
trait ContactRepo extends JpaRepository[Contact, Long] {

  def findFirstByCol1OrCol2OrCol3(c1: String, c2: Option[Option[String]], c3: scala.Option[String]): Contact
}
```

and while calling:

```
val optionData = Some(Some("1234567890"))
val someData= Some(Some("1234567890"))
val simpleStringData: String = "1234567890"
val contact = contactRepo.findFirstByCol1OrCol2OrCol3(simpleStringData, optionData, someData)
```